# Setting maximum length for column field in HiveQL

Tags: sql, hive

I am very new to SQL/Hive and trying to set a maximum length for strings in a column when creating my table as below,

```
hive> CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
Suffix string(5),
LastName string,
FirstName string
);
FAILED: ParseException line 3:15 mismatched input '(' expecting ) near 'string' in create table statement
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Till **Hive version 0.11** you cannot restrict the length of string column. You have to use **STRING** data type for string column.
But from **Hive version 0.12** we have **varchar** data type just like other RDBMS where you can specify and restrict the length of string columns. You check the data types in hive here: [data types in hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types)

Also for create table syntax in Hive you refer to this link : [Create table syntax in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL)

Hope this helps..!!!